# Where can download the souce code of sntp?

Tags: iphone

I will use the sntp protocol in iphone applicaton.Where can i download the souce code of sntp?
   Please give me the address,if you know where can download.

Comment: Is this even programming related?

Comment: Thank you for reminding me，thomasrutter.

Answer (score 8):

i actually found an [sntp class](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) for iphone development. you may be able to integrate this with your application.

Comment: If this really did answer your question, accept it. That's how the site works.

Comment: i can't tell if lqf is being serious or not... he never accepts answers anyway

Comment: Please give me some ideas for where to download the code of sntp souce.Thank you for paying attention to my questions。